# JavaFX "no suitable constructor found for Font(String,int)" when trying to change the label's font

Tags: javafx

The root is a VBox if that has any relevance.

```
    Label cluedo = new Label("Cluedo");
    cluedo.setFont(new Font("Cambria", 32)); // OFFENDING LINE
    cluedo.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    cluedo.setTextFill(Color.web("#0076a3"));
    root.getChildren().add(cluedo);
```

Using NetBeans IDE 8.1:
[image]

Thanks

Update 1:
Here is my code for my main class
https://pastebin.com/BVvbEZQa

Thanks

Comment: RTFM https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html `Font.font("Cambria",32)`

Comment: Can you show a functional code please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call the constructor with the parameters you provided. The constructor needs a third parameter, if you wanted to set the font size too.

Please see [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) for the action you actually wanted to perform.

Your code should be the following:

```
new Font("Cambria", 0, 32);
```

The extra zero is a shorter way to write the `java.awt.Font.PLAIN` constant.

Also as stated out in the comments, you could use a `double` instead of the `int` and it will also work with your code:

```
new Font("Cambria", 32.0);
```

Comment: Oh okay, thanks, I guess the constructor has changed in newer versions, but I still receive this error: https://i.gyazo.com/200cb6809c2943e5040e20849b21ca9a.png
I'll mark yours as the solution though, thanks :)

Comment: I think the error comes from elsewhere, because we can use two arguments as he did : [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html#Font(java.lang.String,%20double))

Comment: @BoHalim yes but you then use(d) a `double` and @Satan.exe provided an `int`.

Comment: You cannot pass `java.awt.Font` when `Label.setFont` accepts only `javafx.scene.text.Font`. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setFont(javafx.scene.text.Font)